# FontAwesome 5 Unicode Support with inline font css

Tags: css, font-awesome-5

I am using a library which does not support a font-weight property but instead fontstyle is defined by font css property as explaned [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font.asp)

So I tested FontAwesome 5 with setting the fontstyle by font css property but it does not work. Am I doing something wrong or is FontAwesome 5 not supporting this mode of defining the fontstyle?

```css
.calendar::before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";  /* updated font-family */
  font-weight: 400; /* regular style/weight */
  content: "\f133";
}

.calendar2::before {
  font: "400 Font Awesome 5 Free";  /* updated font-family */
  content: "\f133";
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="calendar"></div>

<div class="calendar2"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't really have anything to do with FontAwesome.

When specifying `font`, you are required to include at least `font-size` (which must be a size in this situation, not `initial`, `inherit`, or `unset`) and `font-family`.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font):

> If font is specified as a shorthand for several font-related properties, then:
>
> - it must include values for:
>         <font-size>
>         <font-family>
> - it may optionally include values for:
>         <font-style>
>         <font-variant>
>         <font-weight>
>         <line-height>
> - font-style, font-variant and font-weight must precede font-size
> - font-variant may only specify the values defined in CSS 2.1, that is normal and small-caps
> - line-height must immediately follow font-size, preceded by "/", like this: "16px/3"
> - font-family must be the last value specified.

Also note that, if you do leave out optional values, the default `normal` is used in their place, overriding values set previously.

Try instead:

```css
.calendar::before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";  /* updated font-family */
  font-weight: 400; /* regular style/weight */
  content: "\f133";
}

.calendar2::before {
  font: 400 16px "Font Awesome 5 Free";  /* updated font-family */
  content: "\f133";
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="calendar"></div>

<div class="calendar2"></div>
```

Comment: My fault was not to set the font family under double quotes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I see two errors:

- `font` has 2 mandatory properties: size and family. You specified only family.
- The text inside double quotes is a single value, so including `400` makes it part of the value, thus not a previous value.

Try something like this:

```css
.calendar::before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";  /* updated font-family */
  font-weight: 400; /* regular style/weight */
  content: "\f133";
}

.calendar2::before {
  font: 400 1em "Font Awesome 5 Free";  /* updated font-family */
  content: "\f133";
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="calendar"></div>

<div class="calendar2"></div>
```